# Return to Alert Dialog when Check if an Edit Text is empty

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have created AlertDialog with three EditTexts and a button to send the values. if one of Edit Text is empty, it should return to the Alert Dialog.

I use this code to check:

```
 if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_dialog_date.getText().toString())) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter Date", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       return;
 }
```

**If the edit text is empty it dismiss the Alert dialog and return to the Parent Activity , what I want is to return to the AlertDialog itself. 
how to do that?**

and this is my source:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
 builder.setTitle("Add New Bill");

 LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
 View custom_dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom, null);

EditText edtNo = (EditText) custom_dialog .findViewById(R.id.edt_no);
EditText edtName = (EditText) custom_dialog .findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
EditText edtAge = (EditText) custom_dialog .findViewById(R.id.edt_age);

builder.setView(custom_dialog);

builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtNo.getText().toString())) {
       return;
  }
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtName.getText().toString())) {
   return;
    }
  if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edtAge.getText().toString())) {
        return;
     }
    }
});

builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
builder.show();
```

Comment: share your alertdialog source

Comment: @Qasim it is just a simple Alert dialog builder.   final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add New Bill");

Comment: and the button is one of the positive/negative/neutral available using Builder, Right?

Comment: @Qasim the button is the positive button  builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtNo.getText().toString())) {
                    return;
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop dismissing the dialog until you check if all Edit text was filled with the right information you have to leave the positive button code empty and dismiss dialog in the negative button.
After that you have to define

> Alert dialog = builder.create();

then show the dialog and use

> dialog.getButton

to the positive button and set OnClickListener **like the code below:**

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View custom_dialog = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom, null);

EditText edtNo = (EditText) custom_dialog .findViewById(R.id.edt_no);
EditText edtName = (EditText) custom_dialog .findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
EditText edtAge = (EditText) custom_dialog .findViewById(R.id.edt_age);

builder.setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         // leave it empty 
   }

});

builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

builder.setView(custom_dialog);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
 dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
            // write check code
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtNo.getText().toString())) {
       return;
  }
  if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtName.getText().toString())) {
      return;
  }
  if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edtAge.getText().toString())) {
     return;
 }

// if every thing is Ok then dismiss dialog
            dialog.dismiss();
   }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Since, by default, `AlertDialog` buttons will `dismiss()` the dialog, so to prevent this, you have to override the button click listeners as soon as dialog is displayed. You can try the following snippet.

```
dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

   @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {

        Button button = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //Dismiss once everything is OK.
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
     });
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

Comment: That is OK. should I write this instead of the code of the positive button.

Comment: Yeah, just add positive button title with null as listener and then handle button onclick like above

Comment: I am confused where to add this code would you show me how to put it in my source code I have edited my question.

Comment: I have Edited my question with the source code. please kindly show me where to put the code you answered.